# SSL certificate with curl(php) while using amazon web services for PHP

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I have download the AWS(Amazon) SDK for PHP and  put the credential that are required for amazon web service. Then  i run the sample code file name(cli-ec2_sorting_and_filtering.php) that are in the sample folder btu i am getting this following error.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #13; cURL error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (cURL error code 60). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php:843 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\sdk.class.php(1037): RequestCore->send_request() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\services\ec2.class.php(2270): CFRuntime->authenticate('DescribeImages', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\_samples\cli-ec2_sorting_and_filtering.php(62): AmazonEC2->describe_images() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php on line 843`

Comment: please post your php code `cli-ec2_sorting_and_filtering.php`

Comment: this is sample code that re provided by amazon
' error_reporting(-1);
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
require_once '../sdk.class.php';
$ec2 = new AmazonEC2();
$response = $ec2->describe_images();
$akis = array();
foreach ($response->body->imagesSet->item as $item){
  $image_id = (string) $item->imageId;
if (preg_match('/aki/i', $image_id)){
 $akis[] = $image_id;
  }
 }

 // Display
 print_r($akis);'

Answer (score 0):

You have to include this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

if it already exists, you need to change it to false. Hope this helps.